# Fat Tonys motto übersetzen

Tags: translation

Wie übersetzt man Fat Tonys legendäres Motto aus dem Buch Der Schwarze Schwan?

> You do not want to win on arguments. You want to win.

> Du willst nicht bei(an, in ?) Argumenten gewinnen. Du willst gewinnen.

Ist das richtig? Wie würdest du als Muttersprachler den absoluten Killersatz übersetzen?

oder vielleicht:

> Bei (an, mit) Argumenten willst du nicht gewinnen. Du willst gewinnen.

Klingt das ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Du bist nur bei der Übersetzung von "argument" falsch abgebogen. Im Zitat geht es nicht um das Argument an sich, sondern um einen typischerweise konfliktbehafteten Vorgang, also eine Diskussion, einen Streit oder ein Streitgespräch. Siehe [hier](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/de/worterbuch/englisch/argument) die 2. Bedeutung.

Damit wäre eine mögliche Übersetzung:

> Du willst keine Diskussion gewinnen. Du willst gewinnen.

Je nach Kontext ist kann "Streit" auch gut passen.

Comment: Ich denke, der Unterschied wird im Deutschen mit "Recht bekommen" und "gewinnen" herausgearbeitet. "Gewinnen" und "Recht bekommen" ist halt nicht dasselbe. (Siehe "Recht haben und Recht bekommen")

Comment: +1. Etwas freier übersetzt: Dir geht es nicht um die Sache. Du willst (nur) Recht behalten.

Comment: Disclaimer: Ich kenne Fat Tony nicht und nicht den Schwarzen Schwan. "To win on Arguments"  klingt für mich, als Nichtmuttersprachler Engl. nicht nach "eine Diskussion gewinnen", das wäre doch "to win an argument". Für mich klingt es klar nach "Du willst nicht mit Argumenten gewinnen, sondern gewinnen.", also der schlechten Empfehlung lieber schmutzige, rhetorische Tricks zu verwenden, als selbst etwas aus der Argumentation zu lernen. Man will natürlich beides - sowohl die Diskussion gewinnen, als auch mit sauberen Mitteln.